# Mixed Strategy Nash equilibrium

Tags: game-theory

I just strated reading game theory. Consider the game * Battle of the Sexes* with the following pay off matrix:
[image: Battle of the sexes]

The original mixed startegy Nash equilibrium is the one where Men choose *Football* 75% of the time and *Cinema* 25% of the time. For Women, it's the reverse.

So, my question is, if we raise the pay off of men from going to *Football* when Women choose *Football* to 9, as shown in the second figure (marked with red): [image]

Why does women's probability of going to Footabll fall to 10 % from 25% (in the original mixed strategy NE)?( mixed strategy NE from the second figure).

Comment: Can you see why the original mixed strategy is not a Nash equilibrium with the second payoff table?

Comment: @Henry: Because men would play Football, and the orginal probability distributions do not make men indifferent (I think). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: More or less that.  In the second game, if the woman choses a probability of going to football above $0.1$ then the man will always choose football, while if the woman choses a probability of going to football below $0.1$ then the man will always choose cinema.  This $0.1$ critical value is lower than the $0.25$ in the first game because the benefit to the man of both people going to football is so much higher in the second game than in the first.

Comment: @Henry: Thank you very much for your helpful comment. Just a little confusion: what economic explanation can be attached to the fact that their joint probability of going to _Football_ falls from **3/16** to **3/40** even when his benefit of going to football with the woman is raised threefold? Or are these equilibria independant or the probabilities should be looked at independantly of the original ones?

Comment: In this case (both examples), though the mixed strategy is a Nash equilibrium, each would be better off with either both going to football or both going to the cinema (the two stable Nash equilibria) so I would not expect an economic explanation for the mixed strategy.  The real conclusion is that it would be sensible if they talked and agreed a joint strategy between them, perhaps sharing the benefits in some way (e.g. both going to football some times and the cinema other times, or in the second case always going to football but with some side payment to share the resulting extra benefit).